# Keras 3 class image recognition probability output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get my model to output the probabilities of the predicted class however, my model outputs the one hot encoded data instead.

I am using a custom dataset that I have created through various image augmentation resulting in 3 classes of 1000 images each, labelled X, Y and Z. I used the pickle method to store my dataset.

This is the code i used for training.

```
# Opening the files about data
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb"))
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb"))

# normalizing data (a pixel goes from 0 to 255)
X = X / 255.0

# one-hot encode target column
y = to_categorical(y)

# Building the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

#compile model using accuracy to measure model performance
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

#train the model
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.1, epochs=3)

model.save('IR_final.model')
```

As far as I understand, using softmax and categorical_crossentropy is suitable for what I am trying to achieve but the output is not as expected.

This is my code to do image recognition.

```
CATEGORIES = ["X", "Y", "Z"]

dir = "./model_path"
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(dir)

for i in range(1,4):
    image = f"'./image_path/{i}.jpg"

    IMG_SIZE = 50

    img_array = cv2.imread(image)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    new_array = new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

    pred = model.predict(new_array)
    print(pred)
```

In this case, I would like my output to be something

```
[0.1231, 0.1123, 0.7543]
```

instead I am getting

```
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

thank you for your time and any advice/ suggestions provided.

Comment: it seems that your model predicts always one class with probability equal to 1

Comment: @Marco Cerliani yes sir, it does seem that way, do you happen to have any suggestion that could help me achieve the probability output? appreciate the time taken